# Как можно собрать координаты границ районов города при помощи OSMnx? OSM

Tags: python, openstreetmap

У районов города есть тег "boundary", но как собрать не соображу. Тем более, что границы изначально выдаются линиями, которые можно раскрыть и увидеть точки. Работаю с городом Волгоград.

Answer (score 0):

Собрал, используя метод `geometries_from_place` и указав уровень:

```
districts_osm = ox.geometries_from_place('Volgograd, Russia', tags={'admin_level': '9'})
```